# Android Studio - Can't find app icon on TV homescreen

Tags: android, android-tv

When I install my app using a file explorer on my tv, I can run it and everything but I do not know how to create an icon that will sit on the home screen of the tv

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sony.omgandroid" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think that You need `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` instead of `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It utilizes the `android:banner` in the `AndroidManifest` on the `application` tag.

```
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApp"
    android:banner="@drawable/app_banner"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need add in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

`android:banner` `android:icon` `android:logo` and `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`

example:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```